# R Sqldf ALTER TABLE statement

Tags: r, sqldf

Im trying to add a column to a table in R using SQLdf

for some odd reason I can't seem to get it to work

my code is as follows:

```
  new_tab <-sqldf("alter table old_table add Col numeric")
```

I receive the following warning message

Warning message:
In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
  Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries

When I check the new table - nothing has been added

thanks in advance

Comment: You can read more about this in the `sqldf` documentation, but nothing is exported by default from `sqldf`, so you need to do `sqldf(c("alter table mtcars add Test numeric","select * from main.mtcars"))` to see the result.

Comment: Also see [Section 8 here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/versions/0.4-11)

Comment: The warning is caused by the new version of DBI or RSQLite that is not entirely backward compatible; however, it still works so you can just ignore the warning. See the other comments regarding returning a result after alter.